# How to create a controlling terminal while the program is executing?

Tags: c, linux, terminal, tty

How can I create a controlling tty while the program is executing (so I can print the error messages on it)?

Comment: Do you already opened a terminal (like pseudo tty) to be set as the controlling tty?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `TIOCSCTTY` (see man `tty_ioctl`) to set the controlling terminal. However there are multiple caveats as given in the link https://blog.nelhage.com/2011/02/changing-ctty/. See if the solution given in the link is useful.